# routing with htaccess and laravel

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel-4

Hello I am using the following htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

For doing the laravel routing.

When I surf to *example* localdevurl/public/users I get the following error ( 404 )

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /Users/username/Sites/sitefolder/public/index.php/user was not found on this server.

But as u see it shows the index.php in the error. When I put index.php in my url it does work indeed. I have turned on everything in my apache config.

[httpd.conf](http://pastebin.com/7w4tqT6N)

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm assuming you changed the .htaccess from the default.  Did it work with the original .htaccess?https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess

Comment: Nope with the original it didn't work at all i didn;t see my public folder.

Answer (score 0):

In your *.htaccess* file, you are passing the request after the index.php part, instead of allowing laravel routing system to process it, this is:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

should be as the original *.htaccess*

```
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

I had the same problem with the index.php part, this is how I solved: There is a problem when you have *userdir module* enabled, which it seems to be the case based on the URL of the error message.

Possible solutions:

- Create a symlink in the webserver folder to the public laravel project folder of the user web directory. e.g.: `# ln -s ~/public_html/mylaravel4/site/public/ /var/www/mycoolsite`
  Then you can access `http://localhost/mycoolsite`
- Replace RewriteCond and RewriteRule lines with this: `FallbackResource /index.php`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have AllowOverride set to All instead of None for you particular vhost, and also set Order allow, deny rather than Order deny, allow in httpd.conf.

```
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow, deny
```